# Is there a replacement for now discontinued Symantec Corporate AntiVirus software?

Tags: upgrade, anti-virus, updates, symantec

I have been using Symantec Corporate AntiVirus for a few years and I'm very happy with it.
I am now reinstalling my system, and I went to the Symantec site to check for the new release, but I see that this products [has been discontinued](http://www.symantec.com/business/theme.jsp?themeid=eol_av_ce&depthpath=0).

I don't wish to use Norton AntiVirus because it's too heavy and uses too much performance, and I am looking for something that doesn't make that much of hasle, any ideas? please explain.

I would like to emphasize that what's most important for me is the performance, of course, anti-virus should be ANTI-VIRUS, not a kazoo.

Comment: You might want to try [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/security_essentials/default.aspx).  It's **fast, free, and made by the people who made the OS**.   I think that speaks for itself enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symantec Endpoint Protection is just a new name for Symantec Corporate AntiVirus.  You can see that the versions numbers carry on.

If you cannot afford the five minimum licences that you need to but, I have heard that Norton AntiVirus is now much improved since its very bad phase during the last decade and is built on the same engine as Symantec Corporate AntiVirus.

Try the trial and see if it is true.

Comment: I actually don't run any live-scanning AV myself. I just make very occasional online scans and I have one machine that wakes up to scan network drives using NOD32 once a week. My file server is Linux-based anyway (OpenFiler).  If anything does happen I can roll-back to redundant backups, but I have never got any malware since 2002.

Comment: I think I'll just stick to the Corporate 10.2 I have, I just wanna know if it's virus list is updated the same way as the other versions (EndPoint etc.)

Comment: Beginning with Norton 360, most review sites were pretty impressed with how Norton worked. I've not used it myself, prefering NOD32 by Eset for the same reasons Shimmy appears to prefer Norton corporate.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [ESET Smart Security 4](http://www.eset.com/home/smart-security) which includes NOD32. Ive been using NOD32 for roughly the last 4 years on Windows XP up through Windows 7 with out any issues.

Comment: +1. I use NOD32 as well. Though I pair it with the free Comodo personal firewall rather than running the whole Eset suite.

Answer (score 1):

My company uses Sophos because of all the controls it has, however on older machines it is taxing.  Personally I use NOD32 and it seems effective and I hardly notice its burden on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

We were also using Symantec Corporate Antivirus in our company previously, and now our IT department decided to use [Trend Micro OfficeScan](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/products/enterprise/officescan/). As an end user, I can say that it's fast and successful.